# mm:ss calculator from shell prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

From a shell prompt, what's the fewest-keystrokes way to calculate the mm:ss value of expressions such as
`4:33 + 0:20 - 2:45 = 2:08` ?

This is for interactive use, not for use in a script, or measuring elapsed time, or anything fancy like that.  No mouse.  No GUI.

There are thousands of implementations of `mm+60*ss` and `(mmss/60, mmss%60)`, in hundreds of languages.  I could write a script in bash or ruby or C for this, to add yet another implementation.  But it seems likely that this wheel doesn't need reinventing, when it's likely buried somewhere in `bc`, `dc`, `irb`, or maybe even in `bash` itself.

Comment: I'm sure there was one such implementation with `bc` alone but can't remind I will follow up answers in your question. +1 for this question.

Comment: `bc`'s `ibase` only goes up to 16, not 60 :-(.

Comment: looks like there is no short and straightforward way to achieve it with the standard tools. Rather than embedded `date -d` statements.

Comment: if you have a chance to install a third party tool, then I would recommend the `qalc` which does exactly what you want out of the box.

Comment: @deimus, `apt-get install qalc` is easy, but where is its few-keystrokes time calculator? The docs are interactive rather than searchable. (Answer rather than comment, if possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not perfect:

```
s="4:33 + 0:20 - 2:45"
n=$(sed 's/\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\)/(\1 * 60 + \2)/g' <<< "$s" | bc)
printf "%d:%02d\n" $(( $n / 60 )) $(( $n % 60 ))
```

The sed command outputs `(4 * 60 + 33) + (0 * 60 + 20) - (2 * 60 + 45)` to `bc`.

The output is: `2:08`.

Comment: As an answer I then propose this in .bashrc:
`tc() { n=$(sed 's/\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\)/(\1 * 60 + \2)/g' <<< "$1" | bc); printf "%d:%02d\n" $(( $n / 60 )) $(( $n % 60 )); }`   (I'd use this more often than `/sbin/tc`.)

Comment: Better yet, replace $1 with $@.  Then you can invoke it without quotes, e.g. `tc 4:33 + 20-2:45`

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in some few characters on prompt to calculate the time like this.
You can do for example something like:

`date -d "4:33 + 2:22" +%H:%M`

but you need to include time zone (and how time is being calculated), take the output, calculate again and! do not exceed 24hs. So this is ridiculous.
One of the possible solutions can be GNU/Units. It provides shorthand names for some common combinations:

`hms  ->   hours, minutes, seconds
time ->   years, days, hours, minutes and seconds`

`You have: 2 hours + 23 minutes + 32 seconds
You want: seconds
          * 8612
          / 0.00011611705`

Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/units/